# Storage variable inside a function

Tags: solidity

I am reading the solidity docs but there is a part I don't really understand.

In this example:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract C {
    uint someVariable;
    uint[] data;

    function f() public {
        uint[] x;
        x.push(2);
        data = x;
    }
}
```

the doc says that "The type of the local variable x is uint[] storage, but since storage is not dynamically allocated, it has to be assigned from a state variable before it can be used."

I don't really understand what does it mean by "storage is not dynamically allocated" and why the method "x.push(2)" does change the "somevariable"

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> why the method "x.push(2)" does change the "somevariable"

Because when you thought you declared memory variable as `uint[] x;`, compiler interpreted it as storage pointer. Which by default points at storage slot 0 where `somevariable` exist.

*This happens because you cannot declare storage variable inside of the function; you can either declare memory variable or create storage pointer.*

---

To declare array in **memory** it must be fixed sized and follow this syntax:

```
function f() public {
    uint[] memory x = new uint[](3); // size of array in round brackets 
    x[0] = 2; // array.push() is not allowed
    data = x;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. So because we cannot create storage variables inside a function, if you declare one, you must give a pointer to a pre-existing one that was declared outside the function. Otherwise will point to the first one in the storage slot 0 and you will modify the wrong variable. Lesson learned

Comment: Good catch! Easy to ignore this issue.