# How to use local reference type storage variable in Solidity 0.5.0

Tags: solidity, remix, solidity-0.5.x

I'm trying to understand value type and reference type concept in Solidity as per new changes. I'm trying understand local reference types with following example.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Locations {

  function doSomething() public  {   

    uint[] storage localArray;  

  }
}
```

It gives me an error of array initialization. However after doing something like `uint[] storage localArray = new uint[];` (which might also wrong) I found strange error

> Type function (uint256) pure returns (uint256[] memory) is not
>   implicitly convertible to expected type uint256[] storage pointer

Any thought?

Answer (score 1):

You can not declare new storage variables inside functions. You can only declare new memory variables (see [Storage variable inside a function](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/38540/storage-variable-inside-a-function))

Comment: Has this changed since 0.5.0? as its working in older version.

Comment: @Div hmm, that is interesting. What is the use case for doing this?

Comment: There is no specific use case! I just started learning Solidity and try to understand the things.

Comment: @Div In old versions of solidity it is allowed but it is an error because the uninitialized will point to the first storage slot. If you are not careful you might end up overwriting storage variables unintentionally.

Comment: @Ismael, *because the uninitialized will point to the first storage slot* Sorry, but could you please explain it bit more?

Comment: @Div See this vulnerability for details https://smartcontractsecurity.github.io/SWC-registry/docs/SWC-109